# How to use multiple selector with on method jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created two of selection and check up with items was selected by using `on` jQuery method.

I have two of selector id (#idchief, #teller) and I will use `$(document).on` method to check up if an item was selected but I don't want to use **document.on ()** twice. I want to check if on selection was select and process of this selection.

```
$(document).on('change','#idchief', function (event) {

    console.log($("#idchief"));
    var id = parseInt($("#idchief").val());

    for(var keys in cheifs) {
        var vals = cheifs[keys];
        if(parseInt(vals.id) === id){
            console.log(vals.id);
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('change','#teller', function (event) {

    var vals = null;
    var sel = $("#teller").val();
    for(var key in tellers) {
        vals = tellers[key];
            console.log(sel)
        if(vals.id == sel){

            $('input[name=amount]').val(vals.balance)
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried this

```
$(document).on('change','#teller,#idchief', function (event) {

   if($teller){
       //code here
   }if(#idchief)(
     ///code here
   )
});
```

Comment: `$(document).on('change', '#teller,#idchief', function(e) {` try this

Comment: Set a same class for both and then check for it's id and proceed your execution according to id

Comment: @guradio is that not exactly what he did?

Comment: Give the items the same class and use `$(document).on('change','.select', function (event) {
   if (this.id=="teller") {
       //code here`

Comment: if used this it will try to find class selector and return id why we don't used is() method and check on each id selector instead?

Comment: @HengSopheak I like its simplicity :) the .is will look at all props and attributes using whatever you give, e.g. `.is("#parent table tr td select")` -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tushar answer is correct but there is a little issue. If child of `#teller` is clicked `$(this).is('#teller')` will yield `false` which is wrong.

To fix this issue check if `this` is `#teller` or one of its parent is `#teller`.

```
$(document).on('change','#teller, #idchief', function (event) {

    var that = $('this')
    if (that.is('#teller') || that.parents('#teller').size()) {
        // Code here
    }

    if (that.is('#idchief') || that.parents('#idchief').size()) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you are using jQuery version 1.8 or higher, use [`.length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) instead of [`size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/)

```
if (that.is('#teller') || that.parents('#teller').length) {
    // Code here
}
```

Comment: I used else instead of if because it have only if and else conditional  and could you tell me some reason why we need to used size() method?

Comment: [size()](https://api.jquery.com/size/) will return no of elements selected by `parents('#teller')` if that is zero that mean clicked item is not child of `#teller` and condition evaluates to false otherwise true.

Comment: I Downvoted again. I have just tested and .is also triggers on click of the child!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$(document).on('change','#teller, #idchief', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is('#teller')) {
    // OR
    // $(this).attr('id') === 'teller'
    // OR
    // this.id === 'teller'
```

Comment: which one if better between $(this).is and $(this).attr('id') =='teller'?

Comment: @HengSopheak I think comparing a string is better than object

Comment: your code is also work but I just consider with #Adna umer code because it may avoid some inconvenient errors happen.

Comment: @HengSopheak no need to test parent

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give them a class and test that instead

Please note that this.id, $(this).attr("id") and $(this).is("#is") all work:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/0crLLpvk/)

```js
$(function(){
  $("#content").on("change",".sel",function() {
    if (this.id==="sel1") { 
      console.log("sel1"); 
    }
    else if ($(this).is("#sel2")) { 
      console.log("sel2"); 
    }  
    else if ($(this).attr("id")==="sel3") { 
      console.log("sel3"); 
    }  
    else console.log("Not what was expected");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <select id="sel1" class="sel">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel2" class="sel" multiple>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel3" class="sel">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
  </select>
</div>
```